# Trying to setup wordpress with docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, localhost

I am new at docker. I watched videos on youtube and I did the same what I saw codes.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJNg9.png)

But I cant reach my local host. I cant set up wordpress with docker.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDx7I.png)

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Why don't you use the official Wordpress Docker container ? https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshot 1 show you as having 2 running containers **already**.

Importantly, one with port 80 exposed internally mapped to port 8080 on your host machine.

You are then trying to run a **new container** using the same **image** as the currently running container using the **same** port configuration which is already bound - you can't bind the same port twice in this way.

Try running `docker inspect blissful_albatanni`
Then try access the instance via the container `ipaddress:8080`

Your containers are already running and you are trying to run them again.

Couple of good resources while I'm here for getting WP working in Docker:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/#bring-up-wordpress-in-a-web-browser
- https://medium.com/@tatemz/local-wordpress-development-with-docker-3-easy-steps-a7c375366b9
- https://www.upcloud.com/support/wordpress-with-docker/